# Asking for input until desired result, then returning result

Tags: javascript, function, loops, while-loop

I'm currently building a Rock Paper Scissors game and trying to ask the user for their choice and then returning their choice. I'm using a while loop to continue to prompt the user for their choice until it is valid, but it continues to prompt even when I give it my desired answer.

```
    let choice;
    while (choice !== "Rock" || choice !== "Scissors" || choice !== "Paper") {
    choice = prompt("Rock, Paper or Scissors?");
    choice = choice.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + choice.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    } return choice;
}
```

The code functions as I want it to when I don't have it in the while loop, except any string is able to be entered. I'm only wanting Rock, Paper or Scissors to work and then return the choice when one of those options is entered.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [logical AND](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_AND) instead.

```js
choice !== "Rock" && choice !== "Scissors" && choice !== "Paper"
```

Answer (score 1):

you have an Issue with your while loop condition it will always be true change the `||` operator to `&&`, or use the Array.includes() .

```
function getUserChoice() {
    let choice;
    while (!["Rock", "Paper", "Scissors"].includes(choice)) {
        choice = prompt("Rock, Paper or Scissors?");
        choice = choice.charAt(0).toUpperCase() + choice.substring(1).toLowerCase();
    }
    return choice;
}
```